# plotting different columns in r

Tags: r, visualization

data = 110 columns( x1: x100) (numeric)

I am trying to plot all the columns using the following code,

```
      x2=melt(x1)
      ggplot(x2,aes(x = value)) + 
      facet_wrap(~variable,scales = "free_x") + 
      geom_histogram(aes=(density))
      +title(sub = s, line = 5.5) 
      s<-summary(x1)
```

I'm also want to append summary data to every column in the plot for some analysis . Is there any alternate for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, you cannot add a subtitles to subplots of a facet_wrap. You could change the title to accomodate what you want though. Here is an example with min, max, mean and median :

```
data = data.frame(x1=rnorm(100),
                  x2=rnorm(100),
                  x3=rnorm(100),
                  x4=rnorm(100),
                  x5=rnorm(100),
                  x6=rnorm(100))


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

x <- data %>% 
  gather(variable,value) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  mutate(mean=mean(value),
            median=median(value),
            min=min(value),
            max=max(value),
            lab=paste(first(variable),"\nMin:",round(min,2),"Mean:",round(mean,2),"Median:",round(median,2),"Max:",round(max,2)))

ggplot(x,aes(x = value)) + 
  facet_wrap(~lab,scales = "free_x") + 
  geom_histogram(aes=(density)) +
  geom_vline(aes(x=mean))
```

[image]

Comment: but here you are setting mean as geom_vline, but I'm trying to print all values in summary like min, max,...mean under the histogram like a sub title

Comment: @Maddy Sorry about that. I edited my answer to propose a solution